# A triangle in the Poincare disc model

Tags: geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

Suppose that we have a triangle in the Poincare disc model such that the internal angels are all equal. Then Does it imply that the lengths of sides are all equal?

By length of a side, I mean the length of geodesics between two vertices of the triangle.

Comment: Perhaps, you mean that "if the angles of a triangle in the hyperbolic plane"??

Comment: @zoli yes, i mean if the angles of a triangle in the hyperbolic plane

Comment: Then I don't understand the point. What does the Poincaré disc model have to do with a model independent fact?

Comment: In that model "distance" between two points increases when they approach the "horizon" circle.

Comment: With similar method, you can show that if the internal angles of a hyperbolic polygon are all equal then the lengths of the sides are all equal. (This is not true in Euclidean geometry: a rectangle has right-angles for all of its internal angles, but the sides are not all of the same length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $ABC$ be the triangle, with $a = |BC|$ and $b = |AC|$. The angles opposite these sides are $\alpha =\angle CAB= \angle ABC$.

Now assume the contrary $a < b$. Choose point P on AC such that $|PC|= |BC|= a$ and let $\omega$ be the angle of $CPB$. Thus $\angle CPB = \angle CBP = \omega$.

We know that $\alpha + (\alpha-\omega)+\angle APB < \pi$ and moreover $\omega+\angle APB = \pi$.

Hence, we can conclude that $\alpha<\omega$ and a contradiction.

Comment: @willemien thanks for editing.

Answer (score 0):

the triangle is equilateral since if two angles are congruent then the corresponding sides are congruent in any triangle in a Hilbert's space geometry. See Hartshorne: Geometry